# Entity Framework 4.1 and Pre-Generating Views

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce-3.5

I implemented the suggestion in this how to article from msdn, and my first initial entity framework query is still taking 3-4 seconds. The same query comes back instantly with a SqlCommand. Does pre-generating views work with entity framework 4.1?

[How to: Pre-Generate Views to Improve Query Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx)

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Are you using EDMX or fluent / data annotations? mapping

Comment: How long does the initial query take without pre-generating views?  I think there are other initial overheads beyond view generation with EF, that may account for the 3-4 seconds.

Comment: about 3-4 econds also. and to test it, i created an initial query that only queries a tiny table with 5-6 records.

Comment: I looked at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx and it seems that that is the highest performance overhead, so I was addressing that one first. Any ideas as to what performance overhead I should address next?

Comment: Strange, I did a shrink and repair on my SQL ce db, and EF's initial query is significantly quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model-first didn't change in EF 4.1, so yes, it does work.